# Why does function userCanVote() always return 1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Full code in *key.php*:

```
    <?php

class Vote {
    public $db;
    public function __construct() {
        try{
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=voting', 'root', '');
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `voterlist` (
            `uuid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
            `ipv4` varchar(15),
            `votetime` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`))
            CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
            $test = $this->db->query($sql);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die("<div class='container'><span class='alert error'>Could not connect!</span></div>");
        }
    }
```

> ```
>   function userCanVote($ip,$uuid) {
>       try{ $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM voterlist WHERE ipv4="$ip" && votetime>timestampadd(day,-1,now()) && uuid="$uuid"');
>           return(!$result->fetchColumn()>0 ? true : false);
>       }catch(Exception $e){
>       die("<div class='container'><span class='alert error'><b>Error in hasUserVoted()</b><br>".$e."</span></div>");}
>   }
> ```

```
    function getIP() {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
    } 
    function getUserInfo($x,$y) {
        $user = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://mcapi.de/api/user/".$x));
        return ($y=="name"?$user->username:$user->uuid);
    }

    function execVote($uuid) {
        try {
            if ($this->userCanVote($this->getIP(),$uuid)) {
```

> ```
>               echo $this->userCanVote($this->getIP(),$uuid);
> ```

```
                $ip=$this->getIP();
                $name = $this->getUserInfo($uuid,"name");
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO voterlist (uuid,ipv4) VALUES ('$uuid','$ip')");
                Votifier($name);
            } else {
                echo "You can only vote once every 24 hours!";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die("<div class='container'><span class='alert error'>Failed to prepVote() the DB!</span></div>");
        }
    }
}

define("SERVER_IP", "localhost");
define("SERVER_PORT", 8192);
define("PUBLIC_KEY",
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApYVGI2Tk5/8s58bNRdAxJg/12A/xqL8z2NjJI9+fpKH6rPSPn4mjfVJoOWkj0sXQNeE97Y6MrVPUqflBQeCxGwBzbRlb6nyApqhkzRB9pkIn9BGGsYT9CaZcQGmZafY/9Bxz4rpIf6R9NgRfs4HzuNgAxprAi0slUJ2M2SK/VSlNX5OhwRbBTRrUWfUDJMWNUGNvW8XBFd2foyIJ/mdNbbERF8CZZRVpOpq3qe/I04Z6FRt7VfZTWyVSPsHwlbYaZafgql5Szr7SCMcxYQBMMcxsWZDn8uX3RwJbNYcq3Yow/mS9fKTLKdKDxK+lRBU2CfOAKjfvYx/ak04+rUTRCwIDAQAB"
);
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
function Votifier($username) {
$public_key2 = wordwrap(PUBLIC_KEY, 65, "\n", true);
$public_key = <<<EOF
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
$public_key2
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOF;
$address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // user ip
$timeStamp = time();                // timestamp
$string = "VOTE\nNikolovDZN.com\n$username\n$address\n$timeStamp\n";
$leftover = (256 - strlen($string)) / 2;
while ($leftover > 0) {
    $string.= "\x0";
    $leftover--; }
openssl_public_encrypt($string,$crypted,$public_key);
$socket = fsockopen(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT, $errno, $errstr, 3);
if ($socket) {
    fwrite($socket, $crypted);
    return true;
} else return false;
}
?>
```

When executing *echo $this->userCanVote($this->getIP(),$uuid);*, I always get simply *1* as the return value, despite adding a return statement to the end of the class. Could anybody help me out here? There is another file where I actually use this class and its functions, but I don't think that is necessary to post on here.

Thanks!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using prepared statements and supply any user data as separate arguments because you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Comment: Can you try the updated userCanVote function in my answer, i think your query is wrong there and returns always true.

Comment: You're right, it still always returns true, no matter what.

Comment: I still don't understand though the down-vote :)

Comment: The function still returns true, even after your change. I'm very very confused... :')

Comment: @Harry i have revised my answer please check it, it will work 99,999999999999% additionally try to use prepared statements it is better. If still this fails then edit your question by posting a relevant part and schema of MySQL table where votes are stored.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you! I'm sorry someone downvoted your answer, I picked it as best answer nevertheless. What you gave me generated a PDO error but that was fixed once I bound it to _$q_. [link](http://prntscr.com/b1bh4w)

Answer (score 3):

Because you're echoing the boolean.

```
<?php
    echo true;
?>
```

will print `1`.

If you really need to print the words 'true' or 'false', you should do this:

```
echo $this->userCanVote($this->getIP(), $uuid) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any idea why _$result->fetchColumn()_ always returns _false_ no matter what? This happens even when I simplify my query even further. I have checked both the uuid in the table row and the value of $uuid and they are identical.
`$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM voterlist WHERE uuid="$uuid"');`